# JTextField and \r\n problems

Tags: java, swing, string, jtextfield

Part of an app I am working on includes a log file viewer, with a find text function, which calls a pattern matcher on `JTextField#getText()`, like so:

```
Matcher m = somePattern.matcher(textField.getText());
m.find(startPosn);
System.out.println("startPosn: " + m.start());
System.out.println("endPosn: " + m.end());
```

*where textField is a JTextField, and

startPosn is set to the current caret position of the text field*

However the start and end positions returned by this return **incorrect** start and end caret positions, **only in Windows**.
Both the start and end positions are X more than they should be, where X = the number of times a new line is encountered in textField up to startPosn.

As this does not appear in Linux, I think it may be to do with a difference in the way in which new lines (`\r\n` and `\n`) are handled.

Am I doing something wrong; and how do I work arounhd this?

### Impl. solution:

Modified using example in TFA linked by camickr.

```
Matcher m = somePattern.matcher(textField.getDocument().getText(0, textField.getDocument().getLength()));
m.find(startPosn);
System.out.println("startPosn: " + m.start());
System.out.println("endPosn: " + m.end());
```

Note: only first line changed.

This was able to give me the right output in both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it may be to do with a
>   difference in the way in which new
>   lines (\r\n and \n) are handled.

Yes, that is a problem in Windows.

But, I doubt that you will have a problem with a JTextField since they don't contain new lines strings.

I suggest you read [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) which will explain how to handle this for JTextArea and JTextPane.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this:

```
String text = textField.getText();
text.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "\n");
```

Then do your stuff. In the above code you can replace "\n" with something that suits your need.

Comment: I actually want to avoid using a replace function before doing the pattern match. However, if all else fails, I guess this'll be an OK workaround.

Comment: Instead of replace, why not just trim()?

Comment: No, I think trim wont work. Because trim will remove whitespaces only from the very begining and very end. What if the whitespaces lie in between!!:)

Comment: Can you comment on why you want to avoid using replaceAll?

Comment: I wanted to avoid it because 1) There may already be an overlooked API that does it; 2) If 1 is true, I am duplicating code, possbily introducing errors.
As it turns out, 1 is true, see camickr's answer, and my implemented soln.

Comment: there you go Suraj, +1 for you